# Нужна ли здесь запятая: "толстое кривое лицо"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, однородные-неоднородные-определения

Я считаю, что не нужна, т. к. прилагательные характеризуют лицо с разных сторон, но всё же есть сомнения

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: ***толстое, кривое лицо.***

1. **Значения** у прилагательных действительно разные, но **сближенные** в данном сочетании (это **контекстуальные** синонимы). Поэтому определения однородные, интонация перечислительная,  запятая ставится.

Сближение делается **по внешнему виду, по общему впечатлению.** Лицо нам как бы не нравится, оно некрасивое. Мы выбираем определенные черты, создавая **единый образ**, но и выбор этот отчасти предвзятый, **эмоциональный**. Возможно, мы обратили бы внимание на другие признаки, если бы человек нам нравился.

А вот описание **предметов** обычно лишено такой эмоциональности и поэтому объективно: мы выбираем **существенные признаки**, которые наилучшим образом характеризуют предмет. Например: кривой толстый прут, кривые толстые лапы у медведя.

2. **Структура** у однородных и неоднородных определений тоже **разная.**

Можно сказать: ***толстое лицо, кривое лицо.*** Каждое прилагательное характеризует предмет независимо, но при этом раскрывают **общую тему**. Это признак однородных определений.

Но нельзя сказать ***толстое (кривое лицо)***, а именно так построены неоднородные определения: первое определение относится к сочетанию второго определения и предмета.

3. **О контексте**

Обычно такие задачи решаются для словосочетаний, но в некоторых случаях желательно видеть **контекст**: сближение признаков делается по конкретной ситуации и может быть авторским.

Названные определения в отношении **лица человека** не совсем обычны, и возможен вариант, когда они будут просто указывать на существенные черты **без сближения** (то есть без эмоциональной оценки и создания единого образа).

[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98#pp98)

Comment: Похоже, да. А как же другие предметы? Вот: *«Балдой» в народе называли **толстое кривое корневище**, дубину или крупную чурку, полено. / Долгое время только цветовые пятна и размытые круги двигаются перед моими глазами, я словно смотрю через **толстое кривое стекло**. / **Толстое кривое бревнышко**, лежащее возле меня, воспарило и приняло деятельное участие во всеобщем танце. / Джинни видела свою комнату словно сквозь **толстое кривое стекло**. / **Толстое кривое лезвие** сверкнуло сталью кинжала.*

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, ответ дополнен по возможности. В приведенных  примерах нет сближения разных признаков, поэтому определения неоднородны.

Comment: Спасибо вам .Это одна из самых сложных тем для меня .Когда писала это ,вспомнила еще один пример "чудесное морозное утро" .Вы бы поставили здесь запятую ?

Comment: Я бы не поставила: чудесное морозное утро. Второе прилагательное является относительным. Сближение признаков в таком случае возможно, если относительное прилагательное переходит в качественное или употреблено в переносном значении. Например: Его бледно-голубые, стеклянные глаза разбегались.  Но для слова "морозный" такой переход вряд ли возможен. Чудесным может быть любое утро, в том числе морозное.

Comment: Если можно поставить "и" ,то ставим запятую .Вот это школьное правило всегда заставляло путаться .Спасибо вам за подробный разбор .

Comment: Спасибо и вам: объясняя другим, лучше понимаешь сам) Правило действительно "механическое",  формальное, условное,  как и все подобные правила. Но,  возможно,  в нем заключен такой смысл:  если соединить два признака союзом И, то  можно получить единый образ: Пустой, безлюдный берег. Пустой и безлюдный берег. Но это частный случай. Вот другой пример: Настали тёмные, тяжёлые дни. Здесь союз И не очень-то подходит.